# Include all CSS sprite classes in a page

Tags: jquery, html, css, sprite

I have made the FamFamFam Silk icon set into a sprite, and I want to display all of the icons on an HTML page. The problem is, there are 1000 icons split into 2 .png images, each image with its own class. For example, the first icon would be `class="silk1 ad-accept"` and the last icon, which is in the second .png image would be `class="silk2 ad-zoom-in"`. Anyway, it would be crazy to try to do them all by hand, not to mention the time spent and the possible mistakes.

My question is, can this be done automatically with jQuery? Basically, I need a script which will take each CSS sprite class, and apply it to an element like a li. It would be very helpful if it would also apply a title with the class it used, so I know which icon is which.

Comment: Could you re-read you question, fix any typos and make it more clear. "For example, the first icon would be??? and the last icon???, which is in the second .png image would be ???."

Comment: If you have the class names in a format you can read/parse (ie, comma-delimited text, JSON-formatted array, etc.), in a way in which they're related to which `silk1` or `silk2` to reference, sure, I don't see why you couldn't do that.

Comment: @Adam Lynch, sorry, I removed the HTML markup, it was showing OK for me.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Well, I just started scratching the surface on jQuery, so I can't write the code by myself, can you give me some "hints" ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to any set of elements you want using jQuery's [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method.

```
$(function(){
    $(#ads li).addClass('silk1 ad-accept');
});
```

HOWEVER, are you really using all 1000 icons throughout your site? That seems like a great deal of overhead if all your using is a handful of icons. In theory sprites perform better because there are fewer requests, but 5 requests for 8kb icons is much faster than 1 request for a 800k sprite. Something you might want to consider...

Comment: Well, the site I'm working on is meant as a template, so I need to give buyers as many options as possible, that includes as many icons as one could possibly need. But, the images are compressed, so both of them add up to 312KB, which is not that bad IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you are after?

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < styleSheet.cssRules.length; j++) {
        var rule = styleSheet.cssRules[j];
        if (/^\.silk\d+\./.test(rule.selectorText)) {
            var classNameParts = /\.(silk\d+)\.(.*)$/.exec(rule.selectorText);
            var element = document.createElement('DIV');
            element.className = classNameParts[1] + ' ' + classNameParts[2];
            element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element.className));
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
    }
}​
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ddAcY/

Comment: Could you define "doesn't work" a bit more? Could you provide an example of what your CSS file looks like. and perhaps how you've implemented the code?

Comment: The css looks like this: .silk1 {background: url(../img/silk1.png); }, and for each icon .ad-i-accept {background-position: xxx xxx; }. What I mean by doesn't work is I put it in my jQuery scripts file that fires on $(document).ready(), and nothing happens. Nothing in the console either...

Comment: @NovAlex - Is this representative of the form you have (in CSS files), and the "generated" markup you want? http://jsfiddle.net/2kR7Z/

Comment: Only a little different: I modified the CSS a bit so classes like .accept would not interfere with other elements I might add. Now, every icon looks like: .silk1.accept {}, .silk2.zoom-out {}.